# Conditional type conditioned by operating system

Tags: c++, templates, using

What do you suggest to avoid using type aliases in this case?

```
// this is a header file, sample.h

#ifdef _WIN32
using default_type = int;
#else
using default_type = float;
#endif

template<typename T = default_type>
class Sample
{
};
```

I don't want to use type aliases here because I don't want to have type alias in my header file.

Comment: What's the reason for not wanting the alias? If it's name collision, a namespace might be a more suitable solution than a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to use type aliases here because I don't want to have type alias in my header file.

Since you only mention that you don't want to use type aliases, I will assume that you have nothing against boolean constants:

```cpp
// Works with only C++11 or above

#include <type_traits>

#ifdef _WIN32
constexpr auto is_win32 = true;
#else
constexpr auto is_win32 = false;
#endif

template<typename T = typename std::conditional<is_win32, int, float>::type>
class Sample
{
};
```

Comment: ```constexpr```?

Comment: @Bathsheba Right, I will use `constexpr` since it's more concise.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely do not want to use a typedef in your header, you can inline the conditional in the template declaration

```
template<typename T = 
#ifdef WIN32
int
#else
float
#endif
>
class Sample
{
    using value_type = T; // not necessary, but might be nice to have
};
```

With the in-class `value_type` definition, you can refer to the default type as such `typename Sample<>::value_type`

Comment: I like this, particularly if you motivate users of your class via something like `using MyType = T;` inside the class, to avoid any repetition.

Comment: The standard likes to typedef the template parameters inside the class, so it might be nice to have

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define default_type int
#else
#define default_type flat
#endif

template<typename T = default_type>
class Sample:
{
};

#undef default_type
```

Voila: no type aliases, no name leaks.

Comment: For extra rigour, check that `default_type` isn't already defined.